# Getting "undefined" value in $http angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to get values from json in Angularjs 1.5.But i am getting "undefined"

```
function getData() {
  $http.get("processRequest.jsp?requestType=getRecords&page=1& limit=20").then(function(response) {
    $scope.totalItems = response.data.ordersCount
    alert(response.data.ordersCount)
  });
```

JSON values

```
 [{"ordersCount":"100"},{"records":{"MON_FE_ACCNO":"100001810035","MON_FE_CUSTID":"1007","MON_FE_CUSTNAME":"RajKumar","MON_FE_EXEEDING_AMT":"180000"}}]
```

EDITED:

If i will use  $scope.totalItems = response.data[0].ordersCount working fine.why i can't get $scope.totalItems = response.data.ordersCount

Please suggested to me, Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this is an array you need to access `0`th position

```
 $scope.totalItems = response.data[0].ordersCount
```

Comment: You could also rearrange your JSON and use ordersCount as key.

Comment: Thanks sir. @sachila ranawaka

Comment: @j.Doe no problem :D

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @getjackx

Comment: @j.Doe make sure to mark as right answer if this helped :D

Comment: why i can't get $scope.totalItems = response.data.ordersCount

Comment: @j.Doe because `response.data` is array not object. you need to access the element of the arrays using index

Comment: Any example? Please sir.

Comment: make the `response.data = {"ordersCount":"100"}` then you can access it like this  `response.data.ordersCount `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143260/discussion-between-j-doe-and-sachila-ranawaka).